Rabbeinu Yonah's Shaarei HaAvodah online
The Rabbeinu Yonah, famously known for his work on Teshuvah, Shaarei Teshuvah, also wrote a sefer called שַׁעֲרֵי הָעֲבוֹדָה (Shaarei HaAvodah).
Does anyone know where to find this sefer online (free access)? Is it available online?

Sidenote: Shaarei Teshuvaj and Shaarei Avodaj are survivors of a longer work, Shaarei Tzedeq. They were written to be sections of a much longer work, most of which is lost. (I mentioned this to question the story that Rabbeinu Yonah wrote Shaarei Teshuvah as an act of contrition. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66945/1570 )

@MichaBerger Interesting. Never heard of that. Thanks!

The שערי העבודה המיוחס לר' יונה is available at Otzar HaChochma. The first 40 pages are free for the general public and the full online sefer is only available to subscribers or to those who have an account with a subscribing institution.

Thanks. Luckily I found what I was looking for in that version. Shkoyach!
